# 'Machine learning or robotics related' hyphenation?

Tags: hyphenation, dashes

How should 'Machine learning or robotics related technologies' be hyphenated?
Machine learning[en dash] or robotics[hyphen]related technologies?

Comment: It's [pre- or post-trial proceedings](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22pre+or+post-trial%22), and we only normally have a single hyphen in [machine learning-related tasks](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22machine-learning-related+tasks%22), so I'd just write ***Machine learning- or robotics-related technologies.***

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But shouldn't it be an en dash (as used in the first Google search result) for "machine learning–related tasks", or other instances where the subject before "-related" consists of more than one word? It's not exactly like pre- or post-trial proceedings in that way.

Comment: I'm not really interested in distinguishing between hyphens and en/em-dashes, but I did specifically choose those examples because ***between them*** they cover the two relevant issues here (#1: should the first element end with a hyphen before ***or***?; #2: should that first element include an "extra" hyphen?). But have a look at [this Google Books query...](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fitness+and+sport-related+skills%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk03A1NK6WfsjutWhIKB_0nwsN2bsUA:1586345963232&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9h4Sd39joAhVTlFwKHc44Bi4QpwUIIQ&biw=1597&bih=788&dpr=1.13)

Comment: ...where the first match: *Tests are available for measuring **athlete fitness and sport-related** skills* doesn't feature the hyphen I might have included after ***fitness***. But the other one does, with *Every child is provided with numerous opportunities for success while learning **basic fitness- and sport-related** skills*. Essentially, "six of one and half-a-dozen of the other", so I'd say you can just choose the version you like best. It's just orthography, imho only distantly related to ***real*** (spoken) language.

Comment: Thanks again. I will use an en dash (–) instead of a hyphen in a compound modifier when one element of the modifier is an open compound, as in my example.

Comment: Realistically, your options are "machine-learning-related or robotics-related technologies," "machine learning–related or robotics-related technologies," "machine-learning- or robotics-related technologies," and "machine learning– or robotics-related technologies." The option that is least likely to slow readers down by requiring them to figure out what goes with what is the first one. If don't want to repeat the word "related" or you dislike having to use three hyphens, you can simply reword the phrase: "technologies related to machine learning or robotics".